# Python: Extract specific data from a very large JSON request

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to extract the ids and the corresponding names from a very large JSON request and my script get stuck in the terminal. I've been waiting for more than 10 minutes now and nothing, not even an error.
Ideally, I would like to return only the ids for a given names list I supply beforeehand.
Here is what my JSON looks like x1000s:

```
{
     "results":[
         {
             "id" : "156756",
             "advertiser_id" : "taboola-demo-advertiser",
             "name" : "Demo Campaign1",
             "tracking_code" : "taboola-track",
             "cpc" : 0.25,
             "daily_cap" : 100,
             "spending_limit" : 1000,
             "spending_limit_model": "MONTHLY",
             "country_targeting": {
                 "type" : "INCLUDE",
                 "value" : ["AU", "GB"]
             } 
         },
         {
             "id" : "756862",
             "advertiser_id" : "taboola-demo-advertiser",
             "name" : "Demo Campaign2",
             "tracking_code" : "taboola-track",
             "cpc" : 0.25,
             "daily_cap" : 100,
             "spending_limit" : 1000,
             "spending_limit_model": "MONTHLY",
             "country_targeting": {
                 "type" : "INCLUDE",
                 "value" : ["AU", "GB"]
             } 
         },
         // … more results
     ]
}
```

Here is what I've done so far, but I don't even get the chance to see if it works or not as I don't get any result nor error:

```
resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
for id, name in resp.json():
    print (id, ':', name)
```

Could you guys help me with this issue, please? Thank you.

EDIT: I tried an few more times and this time I get the error "Exception has occurred: ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for id, name in resp.json()` is not the right way to get items named `id` and `name`.  Also, those items are not direct members of the json response; they are members of sub-items in the `results` list.

Try this code instead:

```
resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
data = resp.json()
for result in data['results']:
    print(result['id'], ':', result['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You  must iterate through the value for results which is an array of JSON. So instead do the following:

`resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
for element in resp.json().results:
    print (element.id, ':', element.name)`

Comment: Thank you. Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'results'

Comment: I don't believe `.results` will work; you must use `['results']`.  Similarly, `element.id` won't work; use `element['id']`.